# smallest field extension with rational points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

$\newcommand\Q{\mathbb Q}$Is the following true:

> If $C$ is a planar smooth projective algebraic curve defined over $\Q$
>   (so $C$ is the set of vanishing points of a homogeneous polynomial in
>   3 variables) then there exists a point $a=(a_0:a_1:a_2)$ in $C(\bar\Q)$
>   such that $[\Q(a_0,a_1,a_2):\Q] \le \deg(C)$.

And if this sounds easy then I would like to follow it up with some generalizations of it:

1. What if I consider a hypersurface $H$ defined over $\Q$ that is not necessarily smooth instead of a smooth planar projective curve $C$ (I would guess this follows immediately anyway and smoothness would have no influence on the result)?
2. Given homogeneous polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_k$ in $(n+1)$ variables with coefficients in $\Q$ and respective total degrees $d_1,\dots,d_k$. There is a common root $a=(a_0:\dots:a_n) \in \mathbb P^n(\bar \Q)$  of $f_1,\dots ,f_k$ such that $[\Q(a_0,\dots,a_n):\Q] \le \prod_{i=1}^k d_i$
3. Does any of these results change if I require $a$ to be real?
4. Does any of these results change if I replace $\Q$ with an arbitrary field of characteristic $p>0$?

Comment: it feels like it should be trivially true: if $C$ is defined by $f(x,y,z)=0$ then just pick your favourite $a_1,a_2\in\mathbb Q$ and look at $f(x,a_1,a_2)$. If this is not identically zero, then it is a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ of degree at most the degree of $C$. Thus any root $a_0$ satisfies your request.

Comment: Yes you are right. Answer to Question 1. is immediate. But maybe the other questions are more challenging.

Comment: Also I don't understand why you consider a projective variety not the underlying affine variety in which case $\Bbb{Q}(1,a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ has a true and useful meaning in term of homomorphism and DVR of the coordinate ring / function field

Comment: The answer to 1 is still the same. For 3 there may be no real points (consider e.g. $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=0$.) For 4, the answers should remain the same for arbitrary infinite field in arbitrary characteristic, but I think it can break over finite fields, since plugging in values may lead to nonzero constant polynomials, but I'm not entirely sure. 2 looks by far like the most interesting and difficult question.

Comment: In 2) I guess you want to assume that $k\leq n$, otherwise there might be no point at all in the intersection of those hypersurfaces. Anyway, when $k=n$, the answer must be yes by Bezout's theorem: there are exactly $d_1\ldots d_k$ points of intersection, counted with multiplicities. If one of those generate a number field of bigger degree, then its Galois orbit would be too big, since the points lying on the variety defined by those polynomials form a Galois-invariant set. This makes me suspect that the answer is yes in general.